# How to append ndarray values into dataframe rows of particular columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a function that returns an `ndarray` like this

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Now, I have a data frame `df` with columns A,B,C,...,Z ; but the array we are getting has only 20 values. Hence I want to find a way such that for every array I get as output, I am able to store it in `df` like this (A,B,W,X,Y,Z are to be left blank):

```
__| A | B | C | D | E | F | ...
0 |nan|nan| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ...
1 |nan|nan| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ...
.
. 
.
```

Comment: If 20 values are present in the array, which columns do you want as blank? Last 6?

Comment: These are the columns: A, B, W,X,Y,Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get what I wanted through the suggestions posted here. However, I did figure it out myself. I'm sharing it here for the community's reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)])

print(df)
```

> ```
> Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
> Index: []
>
> [0 rows x 26 columns]
> ```

```
list1 = [i for i in range(101,121)]
arr1d = np.array(list1)

arr1d
```

> ```
> array([101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113,
>        114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120])
> ```

```
# Create alphabet list of uppercase letters
alphabet = []
for letter in range(ord('C'),ord('W')):
    alphabet.append(chr(letter))
alphabet
```

> ```
> ['C',
>  'D',
>  'E',
>  'F',
>  'G',
>  'H',
>  'I',
>  'J',
>  'K',
>  'L',
>  'M',
>  'N',
>  'O',
>  'P',
>  'Q',
>  'R',
>  'S',
>  'T',
>  'U',
>  'V']
> ```

```
df = df.append(pd.Series(arr1d, index=alphabet), ignore_index=True)
#This line of code can be used for every new value of arr1d
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

i have created small example of your problem. hope it helps

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
data = np.array([[0, 1],
                   [1, 1]])
print(df)
# df[['B', 'C']] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df[['B', 'C']] = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

**output:**

```
    A   B   C
0 NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN

    A    B    C
0 NaN  0.0  1.0
1 NaN  1.0  1.0
2 NaN  NaN  NaN
3 NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: `from_records` is redundant.

Comment: @MayankPorwal i tried with iloc first but it didn't work. do you have any idea why?

Comment: i tried like this `df.iloc[:, 1:] = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: You don't need `iloc` either. This should work: `df[['B', 'C']] = pd.DataFrame(data)`.

Comment: thank you for your solution, but I wish to append the rows as they come from the function. Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: I've found it. I'll post it as an answer